# Unable to run vmc do to gem version dependency confusion

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, installation, vmc

I just need to know what commands to run to install/uninstall the right gems such that vmc will work. I keep attepmting to meet the dependency requirments of the gem by install cfoundry by get the below error when i run vmc:

```
Howards-iMac:~ Howard$ vmc
/Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1990:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate tunnel-vmc-plugin-0.2.0, because cfoundry-0.4.21 conflicts with cfoundry (~> 0.5.0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/specification.rb:1163:in `activate'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:181:in `rescue in try_activate'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:178:in `try_activate'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:109:in `rescue in require'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/plugin.rb:43:in `block in load_all'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in `each_key'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/set.rb:232:in `each'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/vmc-0.4.7/lib/vmc/plugin.rb:42:in `load_all'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/vmc-0.4.7/bin/vmc:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/vmc:23:in `load'
    from /Users/Howard/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/vmc:23:in `<main>'
Howards-iMac:~ Howard$
```

Running gem list I have:

```
actionmailer (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
actionpack (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activemodel (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activerecord (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activeresource (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
activesupport (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
addressable (2.3.3, 2.3.2, 2.2.8)
arel (3.0.2)
async_sinatra (0.5.0)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
better_errors (0.7.0, 0.3.2)
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
binding_of_caller (0.7.1)
bootstrap-sass (2.2.2.0)
builder (3.2.0, 3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.0)
caldecott-client (0.0.2)
cancan (1.6.8)
capybara (2.0.2)
cf-uaa-lib (1.3.7)
cfoundry (0.4.21)
childprocess (0.3.7)
clouseau (0.0.2)
coderay (1.0.9, 1.0.8)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
cucumber (1.2.1)
cucumber-rails (1.3.0)
daemons (1.1.9)
database_cleaner (0.9.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
devise (2.2.3)
diff-lcs (1.1.3)
em-http-request (0.3.0)
em-websocket (0.3.8)
email_spec (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
escape_utils (0.3.2)
eventmachine (1.0.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
factory_girl (4.2.0)
factory_girl_rails (4.2.0)
ffi (1.3.1)
figaro (0.5.3)
gherkin (2.11.6)
google_visualr (2.1.6)
hike (1.2.1)
hominid (3.0.5)
hub (1.10.4)
i18n (0.6.4, 0.6.1)
interact (0.5.2)
io-console (0.4.2)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-datatables-rails (1.11.2)
jquery-rails (2.2.0)
json (1.7.7, 1.7.6)
json_pure (1.6.8)
launchy (2.1.2)
mail (2.5.3, 2.4.4)
manifests-vmc-plugin (0.4.19)
mime-types (1.21, 1.19)
minitest (4.6.2, 4.3.2)
mothership (0.5.1, 0.3.5)
multi_json (1.6.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.0)
multipart-post (1.2.0)
mysql2 (0.3.11)
nokogiri (1.5.6)
orm_adapter (0.4.0)
polyglot (0.3.3)
psych (2.0.0)
quiet_assets (1.0.1)
rack (1.5.2, 1.4.5, 1.4.4)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-protection (1.4.0)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
railties (3.2.12, 3.2.11)
rake (10.0.3, 0.9.6)
rdoc (4.0.0, 3.12.2, 3.12)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rolify (3.2.0)
rspec-core (2.12.2)
rspec-expectations (2.12.1)
rspec-mocks (2.12.2)
rspec-rails (2.12.2)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sass (3.2.5)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
selenium-webdriver (2.29.0)
simple_form (2.0.4)
sinatra (1.3.5)
sprockets (2.9.0, 2.2.2)
test-unit (2.5.4, 2.0.0.0)
thin (1.5.0)
thor (0.17.0)
tilt (1.3.4, 1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tunnel-dummy-vmc-plugin (0.0.2)
tunnel-vmc-plugin (0.2.0)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
vmc (0.4.7)
warden (1.2.1)
websocket (1.0.7)
xpath (1.0.0)
yaml_db (0.2.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uninstall specific version:

```
gem uninstall cfoundry --version '> 0.4.21'
```

To install specific version:

```
gem install cfoundry --version '> 0.5'
```

Comment: Thank you @BlaineOmega. This is the response I am getting: _Howards-iMac:~ Howard$ gem install cfoundry --version '> 0.5'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'cfoundry' (> 0.5) in any repository
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: cfoundry_ I have verified by running _gem list_ that cfoundry is not installed.

Comment: try: `gem install cfoundry --version '> 0.5.0'

Comment: Thank you Sir, apologies for the Newbie questions.